# Inserting a Node in LinkedList: Does order of the statements matter?

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

Referring to the following PDF(Page 14) corresponding to the LinkedList:

As it is clear that the new node needs to be inserted after the node to which "p" is pointing to.

http://www.cs.utep.edu/vladik/cs2401.10a/Ch_16_Linked_Lists.pdf

My Question:

If we move forward onto Page 16 of the PDF, why does it says that the sequence of statements to insert a node is very important. I mean
can I write the code as follows:

```
p.link = newNode; // writing this part of code first 

newNode.link = p.link; //writing this part of code after the above one.
```

Please let me know what's the difference in writing the two statements in different order?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a pretty significant difference, yes.

```
p.link = newNode; 
newNode.link = p.link; //p.link = newNode, per above, so now newNode.link = newNode
```

Whatever was previously at `p.link` is now lost, no longer linked at all.  And newNode is just linked to itself, so if you follow all the links, you'll end up looping infinitely at `newNode`.

What you likely want is the option below:

```
newNode.link = p.link; 
p.link = newNode;
```

In this case, `newNode.link` is set to the old `p.link`, and `p.link` to `newNode`.

Comment: Thank you for such a nice explanation ! Appreciated !

Answer (score 2):

The PDF is correct.

If you do the steps in the order you listed above, `newNode` will point to itself and the remaining portion of the linked list will be "lost".

Since you set `p.link` to newNode, you no longer have the pointer to what p.link was pointing to before (the next element).  (You could solve this by saving off `p.link` to a temporary variable before assigning it to `newNode`, but this requires an extra variable, when it's not really needed.)

Answer (score 0):

Assume that:

this is your newNode:

```
+---+
| n |
+---+
```

this is your p:

```
+---+
| p |
+---+
```

p.link = newNode;

```
+---+    +---+
| p | -> | n |
+---+    +---+
```

newNode.link = p.link

```
+---+    +---+            +---+    +---+
| p | -> | q |  same with | n | -> | q |
+---+    +---+            +---+    +---+
```

explanation

1. p.link = newNode means next of p is newNode
2. newNode.link = p.link means next of p is same as next of newNode

Comment: Thank you for explaining it diagrammatically.